# The time period format should be in format dd,MMM,yyyy,hh,mm

Tags: json, date

Hi I am sending `JSON` data and the `JSON` will have to validated at the backend. The time period should be in this format---    `dd,MMM,yyyy,hh,mm`.

This is my JSON

```
{
    "equipmentID":"234",
    "modality":"healthcaare",
    "facilityID":"manipal",
    "countryCode":"abc",
    "isoCode":"1234",
     "problemType":"234",
    "problemArea":"priyanka",
    "equipmentStatus":"sdsd",
    "name":"taneja",
    "phoneNumber":"13333344",
    "extension":"12123",
    "description":"x ray machine error",
    "shortDescription":"2",
     "timePeriod":"03-12-2011 04-37",
     "serviceCode":"sdfdf",
     "locale":"werfd",
    "requestingApp":"icenter", 
    "examNumber":"sdd", 
    "seriesNumber":"dfdf", 
    "imageNumber":"dfdfd"
}
```

This is the validation class
    public class RequestValidator implements Validator {

```
    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(String objectName, RequestData rqdata) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult();

        if (rqdata == null) {
            result.addError("error.invalidObjectGraph", "Object graph not initialized correctly");
            return result;
        }
        Validation.rule("EquipmentId", rqdata.getEquipmentID()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("Modality", rqdata.getModality()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("FacilityID", rqdata.getFacilityID()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("CountryCode", rqdata.getCountryCode()).required().maxLength(3).matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")
                .run(result);
        Validation.rule("ProblemType", rqdata.getProblemType()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("Name", rqdata.getName()).required().maxLength(20).run(result);
        Validation.rule("PhoneNumber", rqdata.getPhoneNumber()).required().maxLength(25).matches("[0-9]+").run(result);
        Validation.rule("Extension", rqdata.getExtension()).required().maxLength(10).matches("[0-9]+").run(result);
        Validation.rule("Description", rqdata.getDescription()).required().maxLength(300).run(result);
        Validation.rule("ShortDescription", rqdata.getShortDescription()).required().maxLength(80).run(result);
        Validation.rule("TimePeriod", rqdata.getTimePeriod()).required().matches("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm").run(result);
        Validation.rule("Locale", rqdata.getLocale()).required().run(result);

        System.out.println("value of requesting app is:" + rqdata.getRequestingApp());
        Validation.rule("RequestingApp", rqdata.getRequestingApp()).required().matches("icenter").run(result);
        System.out.println(result.getErrorDetails());
        return result;
    }
}
```

But i am getting an error that the date is not in appropriate format. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Your question says the format should be -  `dd,MMM,yyyy,hh,mm`, but your code checks for `dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm`.  Which should it be?  Also note that `MMM` is the text name of the month which doesn't internationalize well.  My colleagues would abbreviate today's month to "Mär".  Prefer ISO 8601 which is a) a standard; b) unambigous; c) sorts easily  (The format is "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm" or "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm".)  Also, don't forget time-zones.  I recommend storing UTC in the database.

Comment: You should really do the same thing as everyone else and transfer dates as strings in RFC 3339 format when you are JSON (which is almost exactly the same, but a little bit stricter than ISO 8601; unlike 8601 seconds are also required).

Comment: I tried this as well as but still not working   String regEx = "^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$";
Validation.rule("TimePeriod", rqdata.getTimePeriod()).required().matches(regEx).run(result);

Answer (score 0):

Matches would require a regular expression inside it.

Try this

```
^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$
```

This would fit in to check against the MMM for the month

`Time` one of the parameters which have different ways. Please consider epoch format of data exchange for dates. This will be a better choice.

[EDIT]

Change this

```
Validation.rule("TimePeriod", rqdata.getTimePeriod()).required().matches("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm").run(result);
```

To

```
String regEx = "^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$";
Validation.rule("TimePeriod", rqdata.getTimePeriod()).required().matches(regEx).run(result);
```

Comment: No i tried but still its not working.. any other solution?

Comment: What is the type of `rqdata.getTimePeriod()` ?

Comment: String is the return type

Comment: `matches("regex")` this would require a regular expression and do you think that matching against a static string would give you result ?

Comment: do u have any other solution for this problem?

Comment: invalid format M trying this                                                                     String regEx = "^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-d{4}$";                        In JSON "timePeriod":"03-JAN-1992",

Comment: Month has to be `Jan` as in Regex or change the case of regex\

Comment: M using this  String regex = "^[0-3]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$";    and json value is "timePeriod":"01/01/2011" and this is working but i want to add time as well as hh:mm as well as so wat will be the regular expression for that???